# Specialization of image classifing model with user image tagging

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, software-design, training-data

I have a conceptual question, regarding a software process/architecture setup for machine learning. I have a web app and I am trying incorporate some machine learning algorithms that work like Facebook's face recognition (except with objects in general). So the model gets better at classifying *specific* images uploaded into my service (like how fb can classify specific persons, etc).

The rough outline is:

```
event:       User uploads image; image attempts to be classified
if failure:  draw a bounding box on object in image; return image
interaction: user tags object in box; send image back to server with tag
????:        somehow this new image/label pair will fine tune the image classifier
```

I need help with the last step. Typically in transfer learning or training in general, a programmer has a large database full of images. In my case, I have a pretrained model (google's inception-v3) but my fine-tuning database is non-existent until a user starts uploading content.

So how could I use that tagging method to build a specialized database? I'm sure FB ran into this problem and solved it, but I can find their solution. After some thought (and inconclusive research), the only strategies I can think of is to either:

```
A) stockpile tagged images and do a big batch train

B) somehow incrementally input a few tagged images as they get 
   uploaded, and slowly over days/weeks, specialize the image classifier.
```

Ideally, I would like to avoid option A, but I not sure how realistic B is, nor if there are other ways to accomplish this task. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to specialize one learner for everyone, or one learner per user? In any case, what is wrong with taking the new labeled image(s) and running a few iterations of stochastic gradient descent (or some other simple method) on the network as they come? See [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning).

Comment: Yes, one learner for the whole system. Okay, so online learning seems to be the strategy which would let me 'sequentially' update the model with limited, dynamic data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this sounds like a classic example of [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning).

For deep conv nets in particular, given some new data, one can just run a few iterations of stochastic gradient descent on it, for example. It is probably a good idea to adjust the learning rate if needed as well (so that one can adjust the importance of a given sample, depending on, say, one's confidence in it).
You could also, as you mentioned, save up "mini-batches" with which to do this (depends on your setup).

Also, if you want to allow a little more specialization with your learner (e.g. between users), look up [domain adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_adaptation).